# Default Layer in the Inputfield in QGIS processing script

Tags: qgis, layers, default, input, dropdownlist

I am writing a script and I would like to let the user choose the layer but i would like to default a layer (when it is open in the project) in the input field and if the user changes it he can choose another one from the list.
I can specify a the drop down list or a specific layer but then the dropdown option is no longer available. Can I specify a default layer like I can do it with numbers?

This gives me the dropdown list with my layer options from the list

```py
alg_params = {
    'INPUT': parameters['Input_name'],
    'INPUT_FIELDS': [''],
    'OVERLAY': parameters['Overlay_name'],
    'OVERLAY_FIELDS': [''],
    'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX': '',
    'OUTPUT': parameters['result_name']
```

In this I choose the layer, but its not a default, it is hard set and my dropdown list disappears.

```py
alg_params = {
    'INPUT': 'Input_name_d9798079_c0d4_4e60_a3f7_ce2ca427d004',
    'INPUT_FIELDS': [''],
    'OVERLAY': parameters['Overlay_name'],
    'OVERLAY_FIELDS': [''],
    'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX': '',
    'OUTPUT': parameters['result_name']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want can be done when you add the parameters to your processing script class in the `initAlgorithm` function

```py
...
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        """
        Here we define the inputs and output of the algorithm, along
        with some other properties.
        """

        # We add the input vector features source. It can have any kind of
        # geometry.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry],
                defaultValue="the layer name in legend or the layer.shp file path"  # HERE
            )
        )
 ...
```

Comment: perfekt, it worked out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help, accept the answer if it worked, thank you

Comment: Sure, good point.

Comment: Hi Louis, do you happen to know how to define the path to a layer in a geopackage? It not working with just the path I tried it with QgsProject.instance().readPath but I can't get it.

In another Step i load a layer from the GeoPackage by the name with this: C:/Users/.../../Geopacke.gpkg|layername=Potenzial_WEA

Comment: The path seems good, are you trying to load it through qgsvectorlayer() or the processing algorithms input?

Comment: I guess a processing algorithms, I'm pretty new to it. I create my script with the graphic builder and modify it  now. That how the input looks:
self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('WEA', 'Enter Windpotenial ',types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon], defaultValue="Potenzial_WEA"))

The last part i changed I have tried to replace the last part with the above path but it does not work

Comment: Perhaps still as an additional infomation. It is shown in the input field then the path on like a name. I think I'm missing a command that is a pafd and as such should be readw erden

Comment: I don't see where your problem is sorry I've had no issues using geopackages for processing algorithms as long as in the log your input variable equals to  "'INPUT' : 'path/to/the/geopackage.gpkg|layername=layer_name'" works fine, even "'INPUT' : 'path/to/the/geopackage.gpkg' if the geopackage only has one layer